# How to install ibatis plugin on intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ibatis

I have a problem with launching ibatis on Intellij. This is an error:

> Plugin "iBATIS Plugin" was not loaded: required plugin "com.intellij.persistence.database" not installed.

I tried to use openapie.jar, but Intellij fails during initializing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the bundled database plugin. It only exists in the Ultimate version, afaik.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Still some problems with enabling ibatis...